# cursor with if statement

Tags: sql, cursor

How can i write cursor when table is not fix.
E.g

```
DECLARE cursor_1 CURSOR
FOR 
 IF BEGIN @i=1 SELECT col1,col2 FROM table_1 END
 ELSE BEGIN SELECT col1,col2 FROM table_2 END
```

...

This gives syntax error please suggest ?

Comment: This is sql server right? Yum might want to look at dynamic sql and the exec command.

Comment: avoid using cursors, unless you really have to. And even then, don't use them!

Comment: Yes, a little more background info on the problem would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually works, if you write it correctly!

```
IF @i=1
 declare cur cursor for
  SELECT col1,col2 FROM table_1
ELSE
 declare cur cursor for
  SELECT col1,col2 FROM table_2
```

Answer (score 1):

his is an ugly hack, and you'd possibly be better with dynamic SQL, or re-writing this in a more sensible way, but:

```
DECLARE cursor_1 CURSOR
FOR 
  SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_1
  WHERE @i = 1
  UNION
  SELECT col1, col2 FROM table_2
  WHERE @i = 2
```

Comment: That is truly ugly and even has a trailing UNION. Not only that the CASE statement is terrible .. It should just be "WHERE @i=1" and "WHERE @i=2"... if only you can unaccept answers

Comment: @cyberwiki - it is indeed quite ugly, and you're right about the where clause - please note that I did recommend against using it, but it does answer the query...